# Что сейчас используется для динамического выделения памяти?

Tags: c++, c++11, стандарт, c++20, new

Просматривал группу в Телеграме, там было вот такое [сообщение](https://t.me/seniorcpp/1219) по поводу, что `NULL` можно безопасно удалять. Банальщина, но вот в обсуждении люди начали писать, что уже давно никто в С++ не использует `new`/`delete`, и даже placement-new - ненужная фича.

Я до такой степени отстал от жизни? Как лучше всего динамически выделять новые объекты в **современном** С++? Какую технологию использовать? Чем placement-new лучше обычного `new` (мне кажется, возни только больше).

Если не тяжело, не закрывайте как "невозможно дать объективный ответ" :)

Comment: `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `vector` -  покрывают всё что нужно прикладному программисту.

Comment: Если задача адекватно решается старыми проверенными инструментами, то новые ни к чему хорошему не приведут. В качестве иллюстрации могу только сказать, что те же самые, что и сейчас задачи (в ОС с графическими окнами, между прочим) в конце 80-х отлично выполнялись на компах с 16-32 мегабайтами  памяти и процессором на 25-50MHz. И что можно сказать о ресурсах, требуемых им теперь? (правда, следует отметить, что на С++ тогда их не писали)

Comment: Что касается безболезненного удаления памяти по нулевому указателю, то подбные реализации free были в HP-UX (но такое нестандартное нововведение не прижилось, вероятно из-за того, что на практике лучше вовремя увидеть и исправить, чем "замести мусор под коврик")

Comment: @avp вы безусловно правы, но стоит понимать, что бизнес хочет чтобы всё писалось быстро. Новые инструменты хоть и едят больше ресурсов, они позволяют сокращать время разработки

Comment: @SpaceResearcher, в этом вы безусловно правы. Именно стремление бизнеса к росту (т.е. к **объему дохода**) является движущей силой того развития IT, что мы и наблюдаем. Причем, очень часто  эти нововведения (и программные и аппаратные) можно  расценивать как навязанную услугу. Затем все к ним привыкают и спираль продолжает раскручиваться

Comment: Посмотрел на код по ссылке и прямо захотелось сразу в игнор добавить этот канал, названный "Senior C++ Developer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не верьте слухам. У каждой функции своё предназначение. Например, умные указатели, которые сами удаляют объект не помогут, если вы будете заниматься работой с двунаправленными списками. Создавать объект вы будете сами и удалять тоже. После модификации всех указателей надо будет вручную удалить объект.

```cpp
struct dlist {
  dlist * prev ;
  dlist * next ;
} ;
```

А инициализировать объект, который ещё не в неопределённом состоянии можно **только** с `placement-new`. Например, которые в `union` :

```cpp
class A {};
class B {};
struct st {
  int type ; // A or B
  union {
    A a ;
    B b ;
  } ;
} x ;
...
new ( & x . b ) B { } ;
```

В C++20 появился `construct_at`, но это не замена, а  ещё одна обёртка для отсроченной инициализации `constexpr` объекта.

Comment: Что мешает использовать `make_shared`/`make_unique` в первом случае?

Comment: поддерживаю автора этого ответа, все по факту

Comment: массив из `make_shared` просто удалится, когда переменная выйдет из области видимости. Он предназначен только для кратко временных целей.  @BeardedBeaver

Comment: Следить за временем жизни объектов намного проще, чем следить за тем, кто и как удалит созданный ручками указатель. RAII наше все. На счет кратковременных объектов в корне не согласен, умные указатели можно копировать в функции, можно перемещать в функции, можно передавать между объектами и все это с полным сохранением семантики владения

Comment: в стандарте `c++20` ещё не возился, надо потренироваться. наверное можно уже переписывать все учебники на 20-й стандарт. @BeardedBeaver

Comment: А что вы скажете насчет `construct_at`?

Comment: Это всё новьё из C++20 американцы пока увидели только бонус, что можно создавать `constexpr` объекты. Потому-что в простой функции можно поставить флажок `constexpr`, а `new(){}` - не может. *Я даже в `constexpr` не вижу никакого бонуса. Грузят по полной программе, заблудиться можно.*

Comment: Никак не могу, @AlexGlebe. Пока вы ответ не измените, система не дает. Могу только убрать что он принят. Но почему? Мне ваш ответ понравился.

Answer (score 8):

> уже давно никто в С++ не использует new/delete

Их используют только внутри кода контейнеров и умных указателей. (В идеальном мире.) Которые желательно использовать готовые, а не костылить свои.

За ручной вызов `new`/`delete` (вместо использования контейнера или умного указателя) нужно бить по рукам.

---

А начинка *внутри* контейнеров/ умных указателей уже давно принципиально не менялась. Там как были `new`/`delete`, так и остались.

> Чем placement-new лучше обычного new (мне кажется, возни только больше).

Он для других целей. Например, его использует `std::variant`. Или `std::vector`, чтобы выделить память заранее, а объекты в ней создать потом.

Comment: У нас есть какой-то большой класс, объект которого надо создать. Или передавать указатель из функции в функцию. Как тут **использовать контейнер** (именно контейнер, как вы написали)?

Comment: @Mikhailo Имелось в виду "контейнер или умный указатель", конечно. Я думал это понятно. Подпишу.

Answer (score 2):

В бизнес логике почти никогда не надо использовать голые `new/delete`. Достаточно `make_unique/make_shared` и готовых контейнеров. Но если вам надо самому реализовать контейнер (временные ограничения или время компиляции), использовать `union` (например, для алгебраических типов), или написать что-то низкоуровневое/freestanding (например, на некоторых платформах нет `<new>` или `<memory>`, что уж говорить про `<vector>`), то тогда без них не обойтись.

> Чем placement-new лучше обычного new (мне кажется, возни только больше)?

Это разные вещи, new вызывает глобальную функцию для аллокации, placement new пишет уже в выделенную ранее (если вы не забыли) память. Часто вместо последнего удобней использовать PMR.

Comment: Я знаю, в чем разница между `new` и placement new. Я о том, что все равно надо выделять память, только еще и самому вызывать деструктор, а при создании сначала выделить память, а потом вызывать placement new - только лишние действия. Да еще может потребоваться и с выравниванием возиться самостоятельно. `new` же все это берет на себя. Вот о чем я спрашивал - там в комментариях утверждали, что надо не `new/delete` использовать, а хотя бы placement new, если уж не `construct_at`.